# Get "None" Instead of Zero Value in a Python Function

Tags: python, arrays

I want to make a program which puts an array(1x9 has numbers from 0 to 9)  in memory and I want to check if an array I created is previously used. There will be 2 functions I will use.

**addMemory(list,previousStates)** adds the newly created array into memory and **checkMemory(list,previousStates)** checks if the array is previously used or not. It returns 1 if the array is used and 0 if it is not.

I convert the array to a number by assuming that every element of the array is a digit for a 9-digit number.

**Ex:** [2,5,3,4,1,6,8,9,7] is stored as 253.416.897. I want to test my functions. First print has the empty memory and the memory is checked and the array is added and the new memory is checked.

The output should have been

> 0
>
> 1

but I get

> None
>
> 1

Why I get 'None' instead of 0? Can you help please?

```
def addMemory(newlist,previousStates):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,8):
        count += count + newlist[i] * 10**(8-i)
    previousStates.append(count)
    return previousStates

def checkMemory(newlist,previousStates):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,8):
        count += count + newlist[i] * 10**(8-i)
    for i in range(len(previousStates)):
        if(previousStates[i] == count):
            return 1
        return 0

def main():
    a = [5,3,4,7,8,9,1,2,6]
    previousStates = []
    print(checkMemory(a,previousStates))
    addMemory(a,previousStates)
    print(checkMemory(a,previousStates))

main()
```

Comment: You get `None` because you never enter the second loop in `checkMemory`, since  `previousStates` is empty.

Comment: I understand it now. I put it return 0 outside of the second loop and now it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `checkMemory` function, because `len(previousStates)` is zero at first, your `for` statement is never executed and hence your function never reaches any `return`

Comment: I understand it now. I put it return 0 outside of the second loop and now it works